# Personal / custom E-mail Server

Tags: email, server, custom-software, imap

I am interested in developing different types of servers / web services for personal or learning purpose.
For now I've written an [http server](https://github.com/leomonta/sns) that runs (circa) on my machine.

My next idea would be to develop an email server, there are though some inner working of the system that i have not idea how they function.

To be able to send a receive an email with a custom domain what would i need to develop / write myself?

I'm pretty sure i would need an IMAP/POP server and to manage SMTP requests, but is this all? Do i need to pay for a certificate like for https? Am i unaware of other middle-mans that manage some important part of the email infrastructure.

Comment: Of the 2 services, SMTP is probably the more important one, as its used between machines to send and receive emails.  You can have an SMTP server simply write the emails to a disk and then read them with a text editor (or something a half a step up like pine/alpine or mutt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is really "it depends".   Like with your web server, you can create anything from a minimal proof-of-concept server that can send and receive email in the simplest case to a complex commercial product.

I'd suggest that the minimal viable product would be an SMTP server for receiving email into the server and sending email to other servers.  You could just write the emails to disk and read them with a basic reader that can handle mbox or mdir files, but you likely want a POP or IMAP client for a complete minimal solution.    This, alongside some DNS records is all you need to be able to send and receive email.

You could then look at adding functionality like sending and receiving using TLS  (which will make your email more secure and more deliverable) and writing or integrating checks for messages - eg a spam filter, SPF check, virus scanner, grey list server etc.

Some observations -

You might want to start by getting and running a Postfix SMTP server (and maybe dovecot for IMAP).   Particularly when it comes to postfix it is designed to be very modular - so you can likely start with Postfix as the framework and then swap out components for your own (and also use plugins for postfix like spamassassin and postsrs to enhance your own server without the work initially).

All these protocols are documented in various RFC's - so you may want to start your journey by reading the RFC's to find out what is required.   A good starting point might be [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.html).  This starts off with the concepts involved and goes all the way up to the communication details and expected reply codes for SMTP.

POP3 is likely easier to implement then IMAP, and is specified in RFC 1081 and enhanced upon in [RFC1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) and is everything you need for the most basic server to check email.  Of-course this is insecure as it does not handle TLS.

Look at [RFC2595](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2595) for adding TLS to POP3 (or IMAP) and [RFC3207](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207) for SMTP

Comment: You should not need to pay for a certificate - LetsEncrypt offers free certificates to anyone who needs one and controls the website or domain name it is applied for.